# Can't add 'genefilter' package to library

Tags: r, installation, package, repository

'genefilter' package was installed and working for me, however I'm not sure what I have done. I simply used:

```
library(genefilter)
```

as usual and I've gotten the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘genefilter’ in 
loadNamespace(j<- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): 
there is no package called ‘RCurl’
```

I've uninstalled the package and have reinstalled using:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("genefilter")
```

but still receiving same error when I try to load it into my library. I have searched for answers and tried quite a few things but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated as I have a tight deadline!

Answer (score 2):

The correct method to handle an error saying that there is a missing package is to install the missing package.

The method you used usually does also install dependencies. However the authors of the package sometimes fail to include dependencies of dependencies. The installation of dependencies is not sufficiently recursive and you then need to make a separate installation. You may need to make several such "extra" installations. The network of dependencies is sometimes fairly deep. In this aspect is similar to the network of dependencies in varying tissue or cancer transcriptomes. You are a geneticist or student of genetics, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for that. It did work. I just didn't understand why I needed to install other packages to make it work. I am new to R and was quite desperate so apologies for asking such a simple question!

Answer (score 0):

See that **R** is telling you the problem is with *RCurl* not *genefilter*.
It seems that the latest version of *genefilter* or one of its dependencies is dependant on *RCurl*.
install *RCurl* and see if that fixes it.